# Python : ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,086'

Tags: python, string, floating-point, prediction

I've been learning how to make a prediction model by looking at this step-by-step tutorial website: https://towardsdatascience.com/step-by-step-guide-building-a-prediction-model-in-python-ac441e8b9e8b

The data I was using are the Covid-19 cases in Peru from last Jan to this Sep, and with this data, I want to predict death cases from this Oct to Dec.
However, the “New Cases” data type can not be converted to float. So, I added this:

`df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)`
But it did not work too... What should I do?

```
df = df[['Date', 'New Cases']]
df.head()

df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df = df.astype({"New Cases": float})
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format="%Y/%m/%d")
df.dtypes
df.index = df['Date']
plt.plot(df["New Cases"],label='2020/1/1~2021/9/30 New Cases')`
```

Comment: Use decimal point '.' instead of comma ','. Replace, if data comes from an external source.

Answer (score 1):

There could be one of two problems here, but it would be necessary to see the file you're loading and the code used to import it to be sure.  As the error message says, Python cannot convert the string `1,086` to a float, as commas should never appear in numbers in Python.  Outside of Python, depending on the country, commas can either be thousand separators (in other words, the number is meant to be `1086`) or decimal points (in other words, the number is meant to be `1 + 86/1000`).  Python always uses a period `.` for the decimal point, and usually there's no thousands separator (though technically you can use `_` but it's uncommon).

Assuming you're using `pandas.read_csv` to load this file, there is a solution to both problems.  If the comma indicates the thousands separator, you can add the argument `thousands=","` to the list of arguments to `pandas.read_csv`, and it will remove them for you.  If the comma indicates decimal places, you can instead add the argument `decimal=","`, and it will convert all of the commas to periods before trying to convert them to numbers.